# nginx: set cookie in request based on header value

Tags: nginx

I've just started using nginx, and I'm using it to proxy to an application server.  I want to set a cookie in the proxied *request* to the application server *if* a particular custom header is present in the http request.  The logic is:

```
if X-SESSID in request
AND SESSID is not already a cookie in the request
    set cookie "SESSID=$http_X-SESSID"
```

In apache 2 I was able to accomplish this by doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SESSID} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !SESSID [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=SESSID:%1]
RequestHeader set Cookie "SESSID=%{SESSID}e" env=SESSID
```

What would be the equivalent method in nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
# $sessid variable will get a "sessid=$http_x_sessid" value
# if the X-Sessid HTTP header is set or an empty value otherwise
map $http_x_sessid $sessid {
    ""       "";
    default  "sessid=$http_x_sessid";
}

# $sessid_cookie variable will get a value of $sessid variable
# if no sessid cookie passed with the request or an empty value otherwise
map $cookie_sessid $sessid_cookie {
    ""       $sessid;
    default  "";
}

server {
    ...
    # in the same location block where you have a proxy_pass directive
    proxy_set_header Cookie "$http_cookie$sessid_cookie";
    ...
}
```

See description of `map` blocks [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map), `$http_...` variables [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) and `$cookie_...` variables [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_cookie_).

**Update @ 2020.11.12**

Reviewing an answer I think there is a flaw. If a browser sends some cookies with the incoming request, an additional cookie should be added with `;`  prefix to be separated from the other cookies. Here is an updated version:

```
# prepend cookie with the "; " if the other cookies exists
map $http_cookie $prefix_cookie {
    ""       "";
    default  "; ";
}

# $sessid variable will get a "sessid=$http_x_sessid" value (optionally prepended
# with "; ") if the X-Sessid HTTP header is set or an empty value otherwise
map $http_x_sessid $sessid {
    ""       "";
    default  "${prefix_cookie}sessid=${http_x_sessid}";
}

# $sessid_cookie variable will get a value of $sessid variable
# if no sessid cookie passed with the request or an empty value otherwise
map $cookie_sessid $sessid_cookie {
    ""       $sessid;
    default  "";
}

server {
    ...
    # in the same location block where you have a proxy_pass directive
    proxy_set_header Cookie "$http_cookie$sessid_cookie";
    ...
}
```